# after installing aws-sdk gem the website stop working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

My app was working good but after installing the gem 'aws-sdk' and adding s3 amazon storage to my website my website stop working on heroku but it works locally.

Can someone help me

I have gem paperclip for the images

My gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2', '>= 5.2.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem "rails_12factor"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0'
group :development do
  gem "interactive_editor"
  gem "hirb"
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem 'byebug'
end

gem "devise"

gem "paperclip"
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'

gem 'activestorage'
```

initalizer/Paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ':class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

Production.rb

```
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

Here is what I got when I do  heroku logs -t

```
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937754+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/lib/active_storage/service/configurator.rb:8:in `build'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937758+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/lib/active_storage/service.rb:51:in `configure'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937761+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937765+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937770+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937774+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937779+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937783+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937788+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937792+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937796+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:235:in `<class:Blob>'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937800+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `<main>'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937805+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937815+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937820+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937822+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937827+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937831+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937836+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937840+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937844+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937849+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937853+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937857+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937861+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937865+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937870+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937874+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937878+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937883+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937887+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937897+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:85:in `depend_on'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937902+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937906+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937911+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937915+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937919+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937924+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937928+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937932+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937937+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937941+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937945+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937949+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937953+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937958+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937962+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937966+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937970+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937974+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937978+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937983+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937987+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937991+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.937995+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938000+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938011+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938016+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938018+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938022+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938024+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938029+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938033+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938037+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938041+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938051+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938055+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938060+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938064+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938068+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938072+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938076+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938080+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938084+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938089+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938093+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938097+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938105+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938107+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938111+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938115+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938120+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938124+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938129+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938133+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938137+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938141+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938145+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938150+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938154+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938158+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938166+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938171+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938175+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938179+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938183+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-08-10T21:52:17.938187+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2019-08-10T21:52:18.002351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-08-10T21:52:18.540423+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.destination-vancouver.ca request_id=1212088c-dc2a-46dc-8ccf-99c6ffbc4ab7 fwd="96.49.253.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-08-10T21:52:18.818763+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.destination-vancouver.ca request_id=3ad6cb0d-044e-4c15-9ad3-6fd4d259c16f fwd="96.49.253.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove line about **active_storage** from `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

If I understand it correct You decide to use **Paperclip** instead of default rails **ActiveStorage** solution :)
Don't mix them up!